# Can I upload apk having same name having one letter different?

Tags: android

Previously I have uploaded one apk file to playstore,
Today I uploaded an apk having same name but one letter diffeent.
And in the new app the short description and description are same of previous app.
Is it the problem for rejection of the app ?

Answer (score 1):

> You can upload multiple apps with same name with different package.

The package name must be different for both of the app you have uploaded previously and the new one, so you can upload multiple apps even with same name but it must have different package name.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a problem at all. The only thing that is not allowed to change is the package name. 
If you want to rename the app every time you submit it, it is completely fine and not breaking any rules. That is unless you use names that are using trademarks and other protected content but than it will be rejected because the name and not because the name change.

Comment: Hi Bas..Actually I am uploading a new app. not updating the previous one.package name is different.So why the app is rejected ??

Comment: Aah ok, that is a different case. If the name is too much the same it might be confusing for the user and therefor rejected. You shoule always get an email though with the reason of rejection.